# .htaccess point file on one subdomain to another

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What's the best way to re-point files from one sub-domain to another with use of htaccess as illustrated in below example.

Ex: sub-1.site.tld/app.js -> sub-2.site.tld/assets/applications/js/app.js

Comment: Do the 2 sites share a common document root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both sites share the same document root, then your problem is simple. Assuming that you have mod_rewrite loaded, you can add these rewrite rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub-1.site.tld$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?app.js$ /assets/applications/js/app.js [L]
```

This makes it so when someone requests `http://sub-1.site.tld/app.js` the server internally rewrites the request so that `/assets/applications/js/app.js` is served to the browser, and the URL on the browser's address bar remains unchanged.